# Eliminar el código que se ocupa por la rueda y un sensor de un robot para hacerlo tuerto y cojo

Tags: c, arduino

**¡Verdugo, haz tu deber!**

Quiero transformar el código de un robot establecido durante un curso por un robot tuerto y cojo. Quiero hacer un prototipo electrónico con solo una rueda y un sensor sin el módulo *Bluetooth HC-06*.

Estoy siguiendo el [curso electrones-en-acción de la Pontificia Universidad Católica de Chile con Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/electrones-en-accion). Al fin del curso, podemos construir un robot con un *Arduino*. [El código está por aquí](https://www.coursera.org/learn/electrones-en-accion/supplement/z8UzR/codigo-robot-travis).

Me gustaría entender el código transformándole un poquito.

Quiero hacer un prototipo electrónico con solo una rueda y un sensor sin el módulo *Bluetooth HC-06*. Le doy la dirección **'w'** directamente en el código, sin embargo, el *buzzer* está haciendo el mismo sonido todo el tiempo y no se mueve el motor (solamente emite un pequeño ruido), además no está el botón.

¿Pueden ayudarme entenderlo? Por lo menos está el código que da el profesor, las cosas para la izquierda del robot.

Aquí está el diagrama de bloque:

[image: diagrama de bloque]

... y aquí hay otro diagrama:

[image: otro diagrama].

Aquí hay una foto para el prototipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta mi código:

```
/* Sensor de Proximidad con Buzzer (como el de los autos!) */
/* En esta oportunidad vamos a crear un arreglo circuital que nos avisará
* con frecuencias de un determinado tono si estamos cerca o no de un obstáculo
* Hoja de datos del sensor de distancia: http://www.sharpsma.com/webfm_send/1208
*/
#include <math.h> //Librería de funciones matemáticas
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //Librer+ia para asignar otros puertos seriales
#include <Servo.h> 
// Definimos el funccion del buzzer
void Dist_Sensor_Buzzer();
// Definimos el pin del buzzer
int sensorPin = 0; // Entrada analogica que lee al sensor de distancia ("ojo derecho")
int buzzPin = 8;
int led_pin = 13; // Pin que avisará estados
int servoderPin = 6; // Pin del servo derecho
int ang_der = 90;
int button_pin = 7;
// declarar la funccion movimiento
void movimiento(int estado);
//Variable para definir la direccion de movimiento.
/*
0 -> Reposo
1 -> Avanzar
2 -> Retroceder
3 -> Virar izquierda
4 -> Virar derecha */
/*
Definimos una variable para la entrada del sensor.
El sensor utiliza la entrada analogica 0
*/
int estado = 0; 
boolean apagar = true; // Variable para controlar encendido y apagado (condición inicial)???
boolean modoauto = false; // Variable para controlar modo de funcionamiento???
char comando = 0; // Variable para almacenar el comando recibido por bluetooth
int button_read; // Variable Botón apagado/encendido
// Mediciones del sensor
int sensorRead; // Variable que almacena el voltaje leido en el sensor de la izquierda
int dist; // Variable para la distancia medida por el sensor de la derecha
// Tolerancias de distancia. Las usaremos para decidir que hace el robot
int tolerancia_sup = 18;
int tolerancia_inf = 8;
// Variables para manejo de tiempo.
int intervalo; // Variable auxiliar (para comparar tiempos de sonido de buzzer)
unsigned long tiempo_previo = 0; // Variable para medir tiempo (inicial)
unsigned long tiempo_actual; //Variable para medir tiempo de ejecución del programa ( millis() )
// Creamos dos objetos de tipo Servo para manejar las ruedas
Servo miServo_izq; // Servo de la rueda izquierda
Servo miServo_der; // Servo de la rueda derecha
// Creamos un puerto serial por software en los pines 4 y 2.
SoftwareSerial BT1(4, 2); // RX, TX
void setup() {
    miServo_der.attach(servoderPin);
    pinMode(buzzPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(button_pin, INPUT);
    pinMode(servoderPin, OUTPUT);
    BT1.begin(9600); //Comunicación con el módulo bluetooth
}
void loop() {
        if (BT1.available()) { //Revisa si hay información desde el bluetooth. Funciona para el encendido inicial via bluetooth (espera un retorno de línea)
        comando = {'w'};
        BT1.flush();
    }
    button_read = LOW; //Leemos al botón
    // revisar si prende, apaga o cambia modo con BT o boton.
    // Actualiza estado de operacion
    //
    if (comando == 'o' || button_read == LOW) { //Apaga/Enciende
        apagar = !apagar;
        estado = 0;
        comando = 0;
        digitalWrite(led_pin, !apagar); //Robot encendido, enciende luz
        tone(buzzPin, 2000,20);
        delay(200); //Delay para que notemos el cambio de modo
    }
    else if (comando == 'm') { //Cambio de modo auto/manual
        modoauto = !modoauto;
        estado = 0;
        comando = 0;
        tone(buzzPin, 2000,20);
        delay(200); //Delay para que notemos el cambio de modo
    }
    movimiento(estado);
    if (apagar == false) { /* Se ejecuta si el robot está encendido -> apagar = false */
        // Mide distancia y suena
        Dist_Sensor_Buzzer();
        /* ***Servos*** */
        /* Modo auto */
        if (modoauto == true) {
            // if ....
            // state = 1;
            // Valores utilizados fueron encontrados de forma empírica (acá usamos los parámetros de tolerancia)
            // Estos parámetros se pueden variar para hacer que el robot haga acciones a determinadas distancias
            // Como tenemos 3 situaciones: avanzar, viraje y retroceder y 2 sensores de distancia, tenemos 3^2 posibles
            // situaciones que pueden ocurrir (con el conector AND(&&)).
            // Comentaremos lo que hará el Robot en cada una (lo que sería más lógico).
            // Se pueden agregar más condiciones si se quiere mejorar el algoritmo de movimiento(IA)
            // Con este simple algoritmo estamos haciendo que el robot busque siempre pasar obstáculos y buscar la zona que le permita avanzar mejor y más cómodo
            /* Condiciones de viraje de Servos */
            if (dist > tolerancia_sup) {
                // avanzar
                estado = 1;
            } 
            else {
                if (dist < tolerancia_inf) {
                    //retrocede
                    estado = 2;
                }
                else {
                    /*if (dist_izq > dist_der) {
                    //dobla izq
                    estado = 3;
                    movimiento(estado);
                    delay(random(500,1000));*/ 
                    //dobla der
                    estado = 4;
                    movimiento(estado);
                    delay(random(300,1000));
                }
            }
        }
        delay(200);
    }
    /* Modo manual controlado por Bluetooth */
    else { // Modo manual
        /* Definimos las letras siguientes por gusto*/
        /* Si se cambian, no olvidar cambiarlas en la aplicación que controla al robot*/
        if (comando == 'w') {
            //avanzar
            estado = 1;
        }
        else if (comando == 'a') {
            //Virar izquierda
            estado = 3;
        }
        else if (comando == 'd') {
            //Virar derecha
            estado = 4;
        }
        else if (comando == 's') {
            //retrocede
            estado = 2;
        }
        else if (comando == 'f') {
            //Reposo
            estado = 0;
        }
    }
}
/* Funciones utilizadas */
void movimiento(int estado){
    if (estado == 0){
        ang_der = 90;
    }
    else if (estado == 1){
        ang_der = 120;
    }
    else if (estado == 2){
        ang_der = 70;
    }
    else if (estado == 3){
        ang_der = 100;
    }
    else if (estado == 4){
        ang_der = 80;
    }
    miServo_der.write(ang_der);
}
void Dist_Sensor_Buzzer() {
    sensorRead = analogRead(sensorPin); //Lectura de voltaje del sensor (lo que mide)
    // La fórmula de conversión aproximada a la curva mostrada en la hoja de datos
    // es la siguiente:
    // distancia = (3027.4/Vo)^1.2134
    // En la fórmula, Vo es el voltaje que entrega el sensor (lo que mide)
    // En este caso, la distancia medida estará en centímetros
    dist = pow(3027.4 / sensorRead, 1.2134); //Fórmula vista en ejemplo anterior
    // Ahora pensaremos en una función tal que al aproximarnos al obstáculo suene más rápido
    // tal como los sensores que utilizan algunos autos para estacionarse
    // La lógica es entonces, a menor distancia, más rápido suenan los tonos
    // La función que usaremos será f(x)= 36x - 320 . Lo explicaremos más adelante
    unsigned long tiempo_actual = millis(); //millis() mide el tiempo de ejecución del programa
    intervalo = 36 * dist - 320 ; //nuestra función f(x)
    if (intervalo <= 50) { //Condición para evitar números negativos y el siseo del buzzer en pequeñas distancias
        intervalo = 50;
    }
    if (intervalo > 2500) { //Condición para evitar largos períodos de tiempo entre sonidos
        intervalo = 2500;
    }
    /* Esta condición if tiene la siguiente lógica:
    * Mientras más cerca esté el sensor,"dist" será más pequeño y por ello "intervalo" será más pequeño también,
    * por lo tanto, se requerirá menos diferencia de tiempo(condición del if) para que el buzzer emita un sonido.
    * Esto es, mientras más cerca está el sensor del obstáculo, más veces por segundo se emitirá un sonido.
    */
    if (tiempo_actual - tiempo_previo >= intervalo) {
        tiempo_previo = tiempo_actual;
        /*
        La función "tone" toma 3 parámetros
        - Respectivamente pide: El pin de salida, la frecuencia de tono, duración de tono
        - Esta función entrega una señal que siempre tiene el mismo ciclo de trabajo
        y dado esto no cambia el volumen del buzzer
        En este caso generamos un tono de 4 kHz durante 20 milisegundos en el pin del buzzer
        */
        tone(buzzPin, 4000, 20);
        //Ahora solo queda ver en pantalla la distancia medida por el sensor:
        Serial.print("Distancia: ");
        Serial.print(dist);
        Serial.println(" cm.");
    }
}
/* Nota 1 (acerca de la función f(x) utilizada para calcular delay):
/* Elegimos esa función para que cuando la distancia sea aprox 10 cm tengamos una diferencia de tiempo
* pequeña(40 ms) entre sonidos y para grandes distancias, como 80 cm, tengamos una diferencia de tiempo
* entre sonidos de aproximadamente 2.5 s
*/
/* Nota 2 (ruido en la medición del sensor):
* A veces, según la topología del circuito, puede haber "ruido" en la medición del sensor de distancia
* en estos casos. se utilizan ciertas técnicas y configuraciones circuitales (filtro pasabajos, etc.)
* para tratar de "limpiar" la señal que nos envía el sensor. Esas técnicas no están mostradas en el
* presente código, pero deben tenerse en cuenta en el armado del circuito para resultados más precisos
*/
/* Nota 3 (fórmula de conversión a distancia):
* Al ver la curva proporcionada por el fabricante del sensor, notamos que la fórmula de conversión deja
* de ser válida para distancias pequeñas. No hay que olvidar que la fórmula presentada se trata de una aproximación
* de la curva para distancias entre 10 y 80 cm, donde la curva tiene forma de hipérbola. Los parámetros de la
* fórmula pueden cambiarse si se estima conveniente para mejorar la exactitud de los resultados obtenidos
*/
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cual es tu duda, para empzar que micro estas utilizando ? Mi duda es quieres hacer de un robot funcional , un robot tuerto y cojo ? El código ese lo tienes que completar o cambiarlo entero?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que antes de programar (la máquina de estados y demás), verifiques que todos los sensores estén entregando valores y que estos valores, sean coherentes y del tipo que esperas. Así mismo, verifica que los *servos*, se mueven con simples instrucciones.

Posteriormente, haz pruebas unitarias, es decir, prueba cada una de funciones de manera independiente.